# Confusion about integration by parts

Tags: integration

Reading some condensed matter notes after a long break from Physics. I am not seeing how integration by parts works on a scalar function integrated over a volume:

[image: Taken from Michael Cross's Ph127 notes]

I can see that

$$
\frac{d}{dR} e^{-\beta u(R)} = -\beta \frac{du}{dR}  e^{-\beta u(R)},
$$

but putting this back into the original expression I get

$$
\int_0^{\infty} R \frac{du}{dR} e^{-\beta u(R)} d^3 R = \int_0^{\infty} \beta R \frac{d e^{-\beta u(R)}}{dR}  d^3 R
$$

and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: To MathSE, perhaps :)

Comment: :( I feel like such integrals must be extremely common in condensed matter...

Comment: Here is the relevant meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5713/

Comment: Understood. I'll post such questions in MathSE in future.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know $\beta=\frac{1}{k_BT}$, so we wish to check the following is zero: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}d^{3}R\left[\frac{1-e^{-\beta u}}{2}+\frac{\beta}{6}Ru^{'}e^{-\beta u}\right]\propto\int_{0}^{\infty}dR\left[3R^{2}\left(1-e^{-\beta u}\right)+R^{3}\beta u^{'}e^{-\beta u}\right].$$(It's possible the part where you got stuck is the result I used above, $d^3R=R^2 dR\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$.) The right-hand side is $$\int_{0}^{\infty}dR\partial_{R}\left[R^{3}\left(1-e^{-\beta u}\right)\right]=\left[R^{3}\left(1-e^{-\beta u}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty}.$$ With some reasonable physical assumptions, this expression is $0$.

Comment: Thanks very much, I had indeed missed out on the conversion to spherical coordinates! So much to catch up on...